# How to check if two lists don't have similarites?

Tags: python

I need to find a method to check if two json files don't have similarities within each other.

Here is an example of an array of two json files:

```
[32, 19, 1, 2, 71, 171, 95, 92, 38, 3]
[196, 167, 67, 112, 114, 25, 105, 7, 26, 32]
```

As you can see, both of these arrays contains "32".
How can I check if there is no similarities beetween their values in the array?

Comment: Please dont revert my edit. You have shown lists. Doesn't really matter where the come from, or the format they are stored in. If you have a specific problem reading JSON files, then you should ask that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your JSON to lists using `json.load(file)`

Then, add one list to a set and check all elements of the next list against it

```
>>> l1 = [32, 19, 1, 2, 71, 171, 95, 92, 38, 3]
>>> l2 = [196, 167, 67, 112, 114, 25, 105, 7, 26, 32]
>>> s1 = set(l1)
>>> any(x in s1 for x in l2)
True
```

You can do the same within a set (change `x in s1` to `x in l1`) but it'll be less optimal

Comment: If you are iterating over a list again, Then why need to convert one list into set? Why not simply iterate both the list?
`print(any(x in l1 for x in l2))`

Comment: @John, This solution is linear time. That solution is quadratic, assuming that `in` operates on a list in `O(n)` time

Comment: I agree, but why extraa space when same operation can be performed with lists without any extraa space (set in your case) in the same running time

Comment: @John As explained, it isn't the same runtime. `in set` is constant. `in list` needs to compare against all elements. There was no size constraint to the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set's `isdisjoint` method

```
if set(list1).isdisjoint(list2):
   print("there are no commonalities")
else:
   print("there is at least one common element")
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above two solution, they have used `set` and still iterating over it. If need to iterate set, then whats needs to have set.
`set(list)` will take linear time to build set and again iterate the set.

Here is simple solution depicting the same.

```
l1 = [32, 19, 1, 2, 71, 171, 95, 92, 38, 3]
l2 = [196, 167, 67, 112, 114, 25, 105, 7, 26]
print(any(x in l1 for x in l2))
```

Comment: Removed `s1` since you never use it

Answer (score 0):

```
def compare(list1,list2):
    for i in list1:
        if(i in list2):
            return True
    
    return False

list1 = '{"a":[32, 19, 1, 2, 71, 171, 95, 92, 38, 3]}'
list2 = '{"b":[196, 167, 67, 112, 114, 25, 105, 7, 26, 32]}'
list1=list(json.loads(list1).values())
list2=list(json.loads(list2).values())
print(compare(list1[0],list2[0]))
```